Filereader is not reading one file
I am creating this in nextjs(app router). I am trying to get the image from user's system using input(type as file) and reading the content of the file with FileReader().
  const OnChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    console.log([file, reader, reader.result]);
    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log("hello");
      if (reader.readyState === 2) {
        setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
      }
      setAvatar(file);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (event) {
      console.log("Error reading file:", event.target.error);
    };
  };
// this is jsx
          <form className="mt-4 p-2 flex items-center justify-center border-2 border-black">
            <input
              type="file"
              name="avatar"
              id="avatar"
              onChange={OnChange}
              accept="image/*"
            />
          </form>

The problem is the onload event listener is not getting fired
I tried but it won't read the content of file. Even if i have entered correct type of image(jpg,png) it doesn't fire the onload or any other kind of event listeners.

reader.readAsDataURL(file); must be outside of the reader.onload function. Because when you call one of the read method of the reader only then the onload function is called.
Just put reader.readAsDataURL(file) after reader.onerror (at the end of OnChange function).

thank you so much man you really helped me i was stuck for like 2 days on it
